# After Set-ADUser HomeDirectory script Home directory Does not mount

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

The Scenario:
All my users in my AD have their home directory mounted as the following:

\\DC-1\Home$\user

I need to change this path to FQDN to "\DC-1.contoso.com\home$\user" , after I run the script bellow the AD attribute did change, however these changed drives did not mount back.

```
$Cred=Get-Credential

$Server= Read-Host "Type the Name of The DC"

$List = Import-CSV "C:\List.csv"

foreach($User in $List){

    $homeDirectory = "\\"+$Server+".contoso.com\home$\" + $user.SamAccountName;
    
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -HomeDirectory $homeDirectory -HomeDrive S -Credential $Cred

}
```

I dont know why the dirves with changed path values (\\DC-1.contoso.com\home$\user) does not mount.....